# IEEEeqnarray left margin

Tags: ieeetran, ieeeconf

I am using a newfloat in LaTeX. Within that float (called Model) I use an `IEEEeqnarray` environment, as such:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}

\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{model}{thp}{lop}
\floatname{model}{Model}

\captionsetup
  [model]% Float type
  {%
      name      = Model,
      labelfont = normalfont,
      %textfont  = it,
      labelsep  = period
  }

\begin{document}
\title{MWE}
\maketitle
\section{Mwe}

\begin{model}[!h]
\caption{My Model}
\label{Model3}
 \begin{IEEEeqnarray}{l}   
   x_a + y_b \leq c_1 + 1000000000000000000,~\forall~a\in A,b\in B\\
   x_d + y_e \leq c_2 - 1000000000000000000,~\forall~d\in D,e\in E
 \end{IEEEeqnarray}
\end{model}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\end{document}
```

I want to reduce the left margin in front of the equations, how do i achieve that?

I couldn't find anything in the documentation or on Google.

Thanks a lot.

*EDIT: MWE*

Even though I provide the argument {l}, I cannot get equations to be shifted to the left (like in a table cell).

[image]

Comment: Please expand your code fragment into a [minimally compilable example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that exhibits the problem behavior you wish to fix.

Comment: Thanks, I provided the example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IEEEeqnarray` makes no attempt to align the contents with the left margin, but rather it tries to center the block with respect to the margin.

You get a better setup with `rCl'l`, but you may want to change `r` into `l` and `'` into `"` (for wider space). If you really want alignment to the left margin, you can use `flalign`.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % I recommend this

\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{model}{thp}{lop}
\floatname{model}{Model}

\captionsetup[model]{% Float type
  name      = Model,
  labelfont = normalfont,
  %textfont  = it,
  labelsep  = period
}

\begin{document}

\title{MWE}
\author{me}
\maketitle

\section{Mwe}

\begin{model}[!htp]
\caption{My Model}
\label{Model3}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl'l}
  x_a + y_b &\leq& c_1 + 1000000000000000000, &\forall\, a\in A,b\in B\\
  x_d + y_e &\leq& c_2 - 1000000000000000000, &\forall\, d\in D,e\in E
  \IEEEeqnarraynumspace
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
\end{model}

\begin{model}[!htp]
\caption{My Model}
\label{Model3-again}
\begin{flalign}
  x_a + y_b &\leq c_1 + 1000000000000000000, &&\forall\, a\in A,b\in B\\
  x_d + y_e &\leq c_2 - 1000000000000000000, &&\forall\, d\in D,e\in E
\end{flalign}
\end{model}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is your general expert’s assessment of `IEEEeqnarrary`? Is there any reason to use it? Is it as robust as the `amsmath` environments? (The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2e claims that it is even better, but I’m not so sure.)

Comment: @Gaussler It offers many bells and whistles and in some cases it helps a lot.

Comment: But do you consider it as good and robust as the `amsmath` environments? Or should it only be used with caution?

Comment: @Gaussler I prefer `amsmath`, but have no reason to consider `IEEEeqnarray` less robust or to be used with caution.

Answer (score 2):

Use of IEEEeqnarray is not good choice. Better is to use math environments defined by `amsmath` package. For example By use of `fleqn` and `gather` math environments provided by packages `nccmath` and `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{nccmath}  % <--- it also load amsmath

\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{model}{thp}{lop}
\floatname{model}{Model}

\captionsetup
  [model]% Float type
  {%
      name      = Model,
      labelfont = normalfont,
      %textfont  = it,
      labelsep  = period
  }

\begin{document}
\title{MWE}
\maketitle
\section{Mwe}

\begin{model}[!h]
\caption{My Model}
\label{Model3}
\begin{fleqn}        % <---
    \begin{gather}   % <---
x_a + y_b \leq c_1 + 1000000000000000000,~\forall~a\in A,b\in B\\
x_d + y_e \leq c_2 - 1000000000000000000,~\forall~d\in D,e\in E
    \end{gather}
\end{fleqn}
\end{model}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran} % not relevant for your problem

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may also consider to use smaller font size for this equation:

```
...
\begin{model}[!h]
\caption{My Model}
\label{Model3}
\small            % <---
\begin{fleqn}
    \begin{gather}%
x_a + y_b \leq c_1 + 1000000000000000000,~\forall~a\in A,b\in B\\
x_d + y_e \leq c_2 - 1000000000000000000,~\forall~d\in D,e\in E
    \end{gather}
\end{fleqn}
\end{model}
...
```

In this case you will get the following result:

[image]

Comment: I don’t know much about the `IEEEeqnarray` environment, but it’s being strongly recommended in [The Not So Short Introduction To LaTeX2e](https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf). What is supposed to be wrong with it?

Comment: @Gaussler, as far as I remember, it is recommended to use it instead of `eqnarray` (it fixes some of it bad formatting) but not general over `˙amsmath` environments. I may be wrong, however, math environments defined by  `amsmath` for sure are  superior to `IEEEeqnarray`. For example, IEEEeqnarray` doesn't enables  desired solution (out of box).

Comment: Well, the authors clearly seem to think that it’s superior to `align`. We don’t have to agree with them, of course.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I will use your solution for now. IEEEeqnarray has however a couple features that I don't really want to give up on .... I will not tag this issue as solved just yet.

Comment: P.S. thanks for suggesting to use small font :) this alleviates many of my current layouting issues

Comment: @AntonHinneck, the same (or even better) features offer `alignat` environment from `amsmath˙  :-)

Comment: @Zarko thanks, i will look into `alignat`.